# Pertinence des questions "existe-t-il ... ?"

Tags: discussion, question-quality

J'ai vu sur ce site plusieurs questions du type "*Existe-t-il ... ?*" qui n'ont aucune réponse acceptée, et qui n'en auront peut-être jamais.

Le problème, c'est que si la réponse est non, on ne pourra jamais en être sûr. Il y a des choses dont personne ne peut pas prouver la **non-existence**. Par exemple [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/21437/existe-t-il-un-pangramme-phon%c3%a9mique-parfait-en-fran%c3%a7ais), sur l'existence d'un pangramme phonémique parfait, n'aura sûrement jamais de réponse, car s'il existe il sera extrêmement difficile à trouver, et s'il n'existe pas (ce qui est probable vu la difficulté de faire des pangrammes très courts en français), on ne pourra jamais le prouver.

Autrement dit, il est probable que personne ne puisse jamais répondre à cette question.

Faut-il fermer les questions de ce type ? Sont-elles pertinentes ? Doit-on se résoudre à répondre "non", même si on n'est pas sûr à 100%?

Autre question dont la pertinence est débattable : ["Existe-t-il un mot pour ... ? Pouvez vous me donner d'autres exemples ?"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23611/mots-compos%c3%a9s-avec-un-verbe-un-trait-dunion-et-un-nom). Dans les autres SE, on proscrit en général les questions qui risquent de ne jamais avoir de réponse acceptée. Qu'en est-il de French Language ?

Comment: Dit rapidement : sur stackexchange, ce genre de chose a tendance à se régler aux votes et aux flags. Si les questions en question (haha) ont un score positif et ne sont pas *vote-to-close*-ées, c'est qu'elles sont acceptables. Nous espérons tous qu'elles trouveront une solution un jour.